# git Command to remove proxy

Tags: git, github, github-actions, git-config

I have a added incorrect proxy. Below is the one which I was added later I am getting `Unsupported proxy syntax in '12345@': No host part in the URL`

Below line was added as proxy

```
http.proxy=http://username:passowrd@12345@
```

I am trying below command to remove. Please suggest how to remove it?

```
>git config --unset http://username:passowrd@12345@
error: key does not contain a section: http://username:passowrd@12345@
```

Comment: You need to provide **the key** to remove (`http.proxy`), not the value.

Comment: what is the key in my case?

Comment: @ShakeerHussain `git config --unset http.proxy`

Comment: @RomainValeri I tried command was successfully. later I tried git pull origin master. getting this error :  Unsupported proxy syntax in '12345@': No host part in the URL

Comment: Check `git config --show-origin http.proxy`, it will tell you if this config entry still exists, and if it's the case you'll see where it's written (`~/.gitconfig` for global, `.git/config` for local). The command we suggested above is assuming `--local`, just add `--global` if the entry to delete is global (depending on the `--show-origin` test).